# how to set size of imageview in viewpager programmatically?

Tags: android, imageview, android-viewpager, android-imageview

i want to resizing imageview, but my code doesn't works. here's the code:

```
private class ImagePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {


  private int[] mImages = new int[] {
    R.drawable.kuhpps,
    R.drawable.kuhpps,
    R.drawable.kuhpps  
};
```

part of error code:

```
@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
  Context context = MainActivity.this;
  ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);

  int padding = context.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(
      R.dimen.padding_medium);
  imageView.setPadding(padding, padding, padding, padding);
  imageView.getLayoutParams().height = 30;
  imageView.getLayoutParams().width = 30;     
  imageView.setImageResource(mImages[position]);

  ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
  return imageView;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Layout Params` with the height and wight . You are updating the `LayoutParams` instance from `getLayoutParams` , but that won't change the view.

Do like this to change the `ImageView` `Layout size`.

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(300,300);
imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

Comment: it still doesnt work, but thanks for trying to help. No prob, i'll find by myself.

Answer (score 0):

In the viewpager's adapter:

```
@Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        Context context = ActivityGallery.this;

        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
        imageView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(mScreenWidth, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);             

        Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/" + getPackageName() + 
                "/"+....+".jpg");           
        if(drawable != null)                
            imageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

        ((ViewPager) container).addView(imageView, 0);
        return imageView;
    }
```

mScreenWidth is the current screen width fetched earlier.